# Codeigniter module in localhost

Tags: codeigniter, virtualhost, hmvc

I have setup virtualhost on my local machine at home.

I have created a codeigniter setup, which has modules. The main index.php page works, but when I try to get to my module it is not found.

So this works: `local.mysite`, but this doesn't:  `local.mysite/module`

What do I need to change in my vhost file to get this working?

Comment: here i a good place to start check this , http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm

try using

```
local.mysite/index.php/module
```

You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is perfect! I don't know why I didn't think to try it. I have an .htaccess file which removes the index.php already so i just assumed it would work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is .htaccess file. Its in my webroot with index.php. I thought that this removes the index.php? It does work perfectly on my hosting server but not in localhost.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|uploads|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```